# Pyserial tcp/ip example with data processing

Tags: python, pyserial

I have been playing with the [tcp_serial_redirect.py](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/examples/tcp_serial_redirect.py) example in the pyserial gitHub repo.
 I want to log the received data in a liteSQL database but failing as any attempt to copy the data to a global (or class) variable is failing with the process halting at the point of copy. An excert of what I am trying to do:

```
class SerialToNet(serial.threaded.Protocol):
    """serial->socket"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = None

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    serBuf = ""

    def buffer_data(self, data):
        # Printing works
        print("Recieved data {}".format(data))
        # Manipulating `data` works
        data += data.upper()

        # Does not work
        #serBuf += data.replace(b'\x00', b'')
        #partial_lines = serBuf.split(b'\r\n')
        #serBuf = partial_lines[-1]
        #return partial_lines
        # or
        # addLineToLiteSQL(partial_lines)

    def data_received(self, data):
        # buffer the data:
        self.buffer_data(data)
        if self.socket is not None:
            self.socket.sendall(data)
```

I had hoped that I could concatenate `data` and process it when it is a full line. `SerialToNet` is used as:

```
ser_to_net = SerialToNet()
serial_worker = serial.threaded.ReaderThread(ser, ser_to_net)
serial_worker.start()
```

I am sure it should be obvious. Banging my head against this with t&e for too long 8)

Comment: any errors showing up ?

Comment: @maazza No errors. It looks like `data_received` fails/blocks if it has to interact with anything outside its scope.

Comment: Not sure whether to provide a solution or just make some comments...
It turns out that when observing with `python3 -m trace -t ...` that it was throwing exceptions in the thread... It turns out that the thread seems to have a minimal number of modules loaded and any you want must be imported in the function definition. Still there is strange behaviour but worked around most of it 8)